# Multiple options to questions using eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, eloquent

Im creating a survey app, and basically when a user selects a input type of "select" it appears a option input that can be dynamiclly increase, but that im having some issues in inserting these options in my database, im sugin the sync method to insert these options in my table, but is giving me a error of

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'toufarto.question_id' doesn't exist (SQL: select `option_question_id` from `question_id` where `id` = 11)
```

Here is my code:

```
Tables:
questions:
- id;
- input_type;

option_question
- id;
- label_option;
- question_id
```

My controller:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
        {

$this->validate($request, array(
            'label_option'             => 'max:255',
            'input_type'            => 'required|integer'
        ));
            $question = new Question(); 
            $question->input_type = $request->input_type;
            $question->save();
            $question->options()->sync($request->option, false);

            Session::flash('success', 'success');

            return back();
        }
```

My Question Model:

```
public function options()
    {

        return $this->belongsToMany(OptionQuestion::class,'question_id','id');
    }
```

My OptionQuestion Model:

```
class OptionQuestion extends Model
{
    protected $table = "option_question";
}
```

Note: How i could add the label column to the "sync" method, since i  need to insert the label from the option field of the form

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the docs of Laravel you need to define your parameters as follows:

```
$this->belongsToMany(Model,table_name);
```

or

```
$this->belongsToMany(Model, table_name, table_1_key, table_2_key);
```

Looking at your DB schematic however it seems you should make a small adjustment.

```
questions
 - id
 - input_type;

options
- id
- label_option

option_question
- id
- question_id
- option_id
```

Question model

```
public function options()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(OptionQuestion::class);
}
```

Options model

```
public function questions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Question::class);
}
```

Comment: hello, thanks for feedback, i just made this change in the models, but it seems i cant use sync method, it says method is not available, i think maybe is because in the options function im using "hasMany"

Comment: I have updated my feedback, taking into account you really want to use the sync method. which is a useful function :-). 

As far as business logic goes you have to ask yourself the question. 
can many questions have the same option, and many options have the same question.